# iptables redirect to different host/tproxy in docker container

Tags: docker, iptables

I'm beginning to wonder if this just isn't possible to do with iptables, but I want to transparently redirect https to a redsocks (proxyish) server.

The setup is this. I'm in boot2docker, and want to use a upstream proxy that requires authentication.
I'm running CNTLM in a docker container, and the munkyboy/redsocks image. Redsocks is handing everything over to cntlm, which then goes upstream.

Then I've used a line like

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp '!' -s $CNTLM --dport 443 -j DNAT --to $REDSOCKS:12346
```

This works great for anything being NAT'd. It goes through redsocks and cntlm and then the internet, it has no idea it is using a proxy. However as it's the prerouting table this only works for everything other than the host. I want it to also work on the host.
Everywhere talks about using the output table, like

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to $REDSOCKS:12346
```

This seems to be weird over https. Looking at the logs, redsocks gets the connection, passes it to CNTLM, but then cntlm prints this

`cntlm[1]: 172.17.0.9 CONNECT 172.17.0.9:12346`

as a result of
`curl https://google.com`

I think the DNAT is changing the IP dst of the packet? to do the DNAT, and I think https uses that via the proxy. Interestingly enough it's working differently in the PREROUTING table vs the OUTPUT table.

I've also tried the MANGLE table using the TPROXY, but that's only available on PREROUTING apparently. I've also seen people use `REDIRECT` over `DNAT` but that appears to only redirect it to a port on this machine. So not particularly helpful, unless maybe I can point it to the port on the veth device using REDIRECT?.

I'm a bit nooby with iptables, does a guru know if this is possible?

Comment: Thinking about it more it makes sense why this isn't possible. The only two ideas I have now are. 1) Use REDIRECT to the specific interface the redsocks container is on, which may/may not work or 2) Attempt to somehow run the OUTPUT chain through the PREROUTING chain, treating it as a gateway like packet.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand the line _I think the `DNAT` is changing the IP dst of the packet?_ - of course it does - isn't that what you're trying to do?! Also, can you explain in more depth why the `OUTPUT` rule doesn't work as expected? Doesn't it cause outgoing `HTTPS` packets to be directed to `$REDSOCKS:12346`?

Comment: Yeah I was a tad confused myself. What seems to happen is that DNAT on the prerouting chain seems to forward it along, with the original destination intact, so SSL works (eg its picked up in redsocks and the https packet still goes to the original destination, eg https://google.com). DNAT on the output chain rewrites the destination, so for https, its transforming the CONNECT `googles ip` to be seen as CONNECT `the ip address of the forwarder`, which isn't very useful for https :). Everyone seems to use REDIRECT with output to a proxy running on the same machine :(.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. I think that the `PREROUTING` rule should also modify the packet's destination. Are you sure it doesn't? Also, if you want the destination to remain intact, can't you just change the default gateway to be `$REDSOCKS`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with Docker itself and not have to mess with iptables at all.